# Join unique values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a `#temp` table like this:

```
ID              Connection  
---------------------------
ID100931969     C170893167  
ID451076784     C170893167
```

I want to join same structured data in `Tempo` like this, on Connection:

```
ID          Connection  
----------------------
ID100931969 C170893167  
ID451123343 C170893167
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
select  
    t.ID,
    t.Connection,
    t.Detail_ID 
from 
    #temp t
join 
    Tempo as s on s.Connection = t.Connection   
where 
    t.ID <> s.ID
```

Problem here is that I don't want to join same data in both tables, so if `t.ID=s.ID` and `t.Connection=s.Connection` I don't want to join this data, in this example:

ID100931969 and C170893167.

Hope I explained clearly.

Comment: please show the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your condition like following.

```
select  t.ID,
 t.Connection,
 t.Detail_ID 
from #temp t
 join Tempo as s on s.Connection<> t.Connection and    t.ID<>s.ID
```

This will join all the records which are not matching based on `connection` and `id`

Looking at your scenario, it seems you want record from `#temp` table which are not matching in `Tempo`, for this you can use `NOT EXISTS` like following.

```
select  t.ID,
 t.Connection,
 t.Detail_ID 
from #temp t
 where not exists
 (
  select 1 from Tempo t1 where t1.id=t.id and t.connection=t1.connection
 )
```

Comment: in the second query, `t2` should be `t`

Comment: in the first example of code it will still join because we got ID451076784     C170893167 this record so C170893167  will join to tempo's connection C170893167,  where ID = ID451123343 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query if you want to fetch all the records from #temp which does not exist in the tempo

**Note:**  This will work if both the table have the same structure (columns)

```
select * from #temp  
EXCEPT  
select * from tempo
```